# ios 11 - Icons alignment distortion

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, xcode9-beta

We had to create a 64bit build of our application, due to iOS 11 enforcement. We've effectively done that but stuck in icons alignment in our XIB files.

In our old builds the icons used to appear like vertically aligned. But now the icons are appearing horizontally aligned with text. I have tried to set custom offsets, apply Auto Layout and Trait Variations from Interface builder Document properties.

How it appears as of now in other devices, this is the desired behavior as well:
[image: iOS 8, iOS 10 Icons appearance]

How it appears right now:
[image: iOS 11 Icons Appearance]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios 11 UITabBar UITabBarItem positioning issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822558/ios-11-uitabbar-uitabbaritem-positioning-issue)

Answer (score 0):

> It's the new feature of iOS 11 User Interface on iPad (refer to [this WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/204/)).

I don't think you can do anything with standard exposed configuration options unless you use a custom component.

Or you can subclass and trick the component to think that it's always in compact size class as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45945937/1463411