# TabBar Icons positioning

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

Before iOS 11 and Xcode 9 the Icons in the TabBar were equally spaced.

Now after the Update the Icons are not placed correctly, see here [image: Screenshot]
On the left an right side is unused and unwanted space.

I tried to switch in the IB the 'Items position' from fill to centered  and vice versa, but it takes no effect.
I also set in the TabBarViewController the line

```
self.tabBar.itemPositioning = .fill
```

But nothing changed

Did someone noticed the same and have a solution or something else I could try ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822558/ios-11-uitabbar-uitabbaritem-positioning-issue

Answer (score 0):

in iOS 11 Tab Bar position item equally towards centre so it will leave some space form left and right