# UITabBar item position issue Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm new in Xamarin iOS development. In iOS 11 UITabBar appearance has been changed for iPad in portrait and landscape mode. If I build an application with base sdk less than iOS 11 then it is showing properly as expected. But if I build with iOS 11 sdk then its appearance get changed (Actual). So I want to keep the previous appearance (Expected) as it is in iOS 11 also (With base sdk iOS 11 and above). I tried to apply native (Objective C and swift) solutions to it and still no luck.

Actual:
[image]

Expected:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this.

Regards,
Hrishikesh Pol.

Answer (score -1):

You've described properly how the tab bar behaves on iOS 11. It is like that by design. If you don't like it you can use the toolbar control (or even a simple view) to build your own custom tab bar and make it look whatever you like it to be.

Comment: Its not about liking. Its an client requirement. And in native we have so many working solutions for this. See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822558/ios-11-uitabbar-uitabbaritem-positioning-issue

Comment: @Hrishikesh Every solution in native is possible in Xamarin, so try to port that code.

Comment: Can you help me for this situation then. That will be great help.

Comment: @Hrishikesh I do answer here for the questions that I can answer top of the mind (one can see that from my score that I answered many times by now). If I need to do some work I answer only if it is charged (like on Freelancer or Guru). Unfortunately, I don't know to translate that code without some work :(. Wish you good luck.

Comment: Xamarin.ios doesn't provide the method `traitCollection ` which can override  in UITabbar. I think you have to custom tabbar if you want the expect style..

Comment: Thank you @ColeXia. I'll try it.